# How to implement rotating wheels in picker like date picker (Xcode)

Tags: xcode, uipickerview, rotation

I want rotating wheels like date picker in simple UIPickerView for each component.
I don't know how can I achieve this. I was thinking to have circular array and set it for each component. But not sure wether it will work or not.

Any one know how to get your component rotating like date picker?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like the regular wheel, instead this time set number of components (aka number of wheels) to 2 for 2 wheels. Example:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 2;  // 2 wheels 
}
```